# Open URL via cmd without opening a browser

Tags: php, browser, cron, cmd

I wanted to use my local server which is running Windows 7 to take advantage of the task scheduler to setup some cron jobs for some of my php files.

I can do this currently by:
`start http://theurl`

Which opens in my default browser. However I was hoping to accomplish this without physically opening  a browser so when I come back to my computer after a few days I don't have millions of Chrome windows open.

How can I load a URL in Task scheduler without opening a browser client via `cmd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the cron job by using a program called [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). I setup task scheduler to run the wget.exe at my specified time with these arguments:

```
   wget -q -O - http://theurl.com > tmp.txt
```

This would load the website and store it to a temporary text file which is overwritten next time it is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to run some php files you don't need a browser. You can just run it from the commandline:

```
php -f /path/to/php/file.php
```

However if you really need to access a page you can do several things like: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or making a [cURL request](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) from PHP.

Comment: If it is simple file, yes. With dynamic pages, you get errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cmd or shell access. If your host has the HTTP wrapper enabled, a call to [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) is all you need:

```
file_get_contents( 'http://theurl');
```

You can also use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) if you're not interested in the response from the server.

Comment: Just to clarify: I can use fopen() in task scheduler to hit the webpage I want to be updated as I am not interest in the response just the action of having the php run at a certain time.